# How to work out confidence intervals for the following two scenarios? (please see description below)

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, chi-squared-distribution

I've got a linear regression sas output. So, I know the standard error from there. I need to work out the 95% confidence interval for the change in y as x increase by 1, which is basically the confidence interval of the slope I think. So, according to some research I have done, I need to work out critial t value first. I have sample size of 31, so df=31-2=29, and found the critical value for 95% to be 2.045. So I took the parameter estimate of x +/- t-critical value(2.045)*standard error of x. parameter estimate and standard error taken from the aforementioned sas output for regression. I am just not sure if I have done this correctly or if I should take z-critical value, if so how?

2nd scenario is chi-sq test. 3 treatments. recorded yes or no for disease. i worked out the expected values this way. (total number of treatment 1 * total number of diseased) / total sample size, for expected number of people who have disease with treatment 1 and so on. Please comment on if I got this right. and then I worked out the chi-sq. And then, I need to work out the 95% confidence interval for difference in rate of disease incidence (yes-disease) between participents of treatment 2 and 3. I am just completely at a loss here. i found thid potentially useful formula. CI = sample mean +/- z*(s/square-root of n). s is sample standard deviation. but no idea what sample mean would be in chi-sq test or how to find s or z.